# "Content is not allowed in prolog" error for Mule Core Schema

Tags: mule, saxparseexception

While running my mule configuration file, I am getting SAXParserException "Content is not allowed in prolog" in the line:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
            ...... 
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.0/mule.xsd 
    .......

</mule>
```

When I open http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.0/mule.xsd in browser, it shows this warning message before the starting of the XSD file:

Warning: fopen(./logs/proxy-2012-09.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/domains/mulesoft.org/mule/drupal/drupal-6.25/mule-schema/proxy.php on line 56

and some more warnings.

Can somebody suggest any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been some outage during the weekend with MuleSoft's servers hosting the XSDs.

However the resolution of the schema through the web is only a fallback and no application should rely on it.

To make sure that the schema are retrieved from the jars and not from the internet you need to the the schema version (e.g. 3.0 ) to the same version of the jars included in your classpath.

If you are using mule >= 3.2 it is recommended to use the current version.